# NavigationDrawer activity doesn't keep keyboard's state on orientation change

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-softkeyboard

I created sample project using Android Studio: Create new Project -> Navigation Drawer Activity. In testing purposes, my content `Fragment`contains just a single `EditText` widget.

In my `AndroidManifest` I have this line for the main activity:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustResize"
```

Odd behavior: if I launch the app in portrait mode, open soft keyboard (by tapping on the `EditText`) and rotate device to landscape mode... keyboard disappears for some reason. If I create the same project but with no `NavigationDrawer` (just Activity + Fragment) the keyboard remains visible (as expected with `stateUnchanged` property).

Did anyone know what is the reason of such behavior? Actually I want to keep the keyboard expanded after switching to landscape mode (if it was opened in portrait). I can track keyboard state and via special flag restore its visibility when needed programmatically, I know. I just wonder why the native tools don't work with `NavigationDrawer`.

Comment: My observations: 1. This issue is not seen in Gingerbread. 2. If a spinner drop-down menu is open, the keyboard state is restored correctly on rotation, so maybe a hacky workaround would be to create some invisible window prior to rotation. How did you address this problem?

Comment: I'm doing everything manually for now: track rotations, check keyboard's visibility, show/hide the keyboard manually when necessary.

Comment: Is there any way to determine if the keyboard is visible in full screen (in landscape)?

Comment: Yes there is (orientation doesn't actually matter). From my opinion one of the most reliable solutions for that could be found at Telegram for Android - https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram

Comment: Are you sure they use the keyboard in full screen when the device is in landscape?
I noticed EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI is used in multiple places to avoid the keyboard being set to full screen.
Can you please point me to the relevant place in their code? Thanks!

Comment: Yes I am sure. Try to install their app and if that's what you need should start from there - https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/ui/Components/ChatActivityEnterView.java